# Using local package repository instead of public pypi for setuptools in virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, setuptools

I have a virtualenv where I am installing a number of packages from pip using an intranet repository (the machine does not have internet access). I have a `pip.conf` in the virtualenv directory and pip uses this without issue. However, there is one package with a `setup.py` file using the `setup_requires` option. Since this does not use pip but rather easy_install to grab dependencies, it does not use the repository specified in the virtualenv's `pip.conf` (see https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#controlling-setup-requires).

The apparent solution to this is to create a distutils configuration file to specify the intranet repository I want to use.

This worked ok when I created a user-specific config file at `~/.pydistutils.cfg`, however this is not a portable solution as I can't be overwriting files in my colleagues' home directories whenever they use my virtualenv. I was hoping to be able to specify the distutils configuration inside the virtualenv itself, but I can't seem to figure out how to do this.

The distutils configuration document seemed to suggest that I could put a file here:

`prefix/lib/pythonver/distutils/distutils.cfg`, however this did not appear to work for me.

The contents of this config is essentially:

```
[easy_install]
allow_hosts = internalhostname
index_url = http://internalhostname/artifactory/api/pypi/pypi/simple
```

I am actually using setuptools in my virtualenv, but a lot of the documentation for setuptools seems to refer to distutils configuration (e.g. see http://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/easy_install.html#configuration-files)

How can I have setuptools within the virtualenv use a specific package repository without requiring a user-specific or system-wide configuration change?

Comment: @hoefling I'm running a `pip install -r requirements.txt` command with the venv activated. One of the packages that comes along after resolving dependencies has the `setup_requires` portion in its `setup.py`. The package it tries to get can't be downloaded from pypi because the machine is cannot access the internet. Is evaluating the `setup_requires` not expected if I'm only doing a pip install?

Comment: @hoefling it looks like the file being downloaded is a `.tar.gz` file. I updated the question to show a representation of the config file. I tried putting the distutils.cfg in a few places, including `/path/to/venv/lib/pythonX.X/distutils/distutils.cfg` or also `/path/to/venv/.pydistutils.cfg`

Comment: Poking through the setuptools code, where resolves the paths to the distutils config files, I observed that it imports distutils, then uses `os.path.dirname(distutils.__file__)` to get the directory where it expects `distutils.cfg` to be. In my venv, this resolved to the host system's global distutils (e.g. `/usr/lib/pythonX.X/distutils/`) instead of anything in the venv. I guess distutils isn't packaged into a venv?

Comment: Interesting, so I checked that (printing `distutils.__file__` from within an activated virtualenv) on the server of interest, on my local Debian system, and also on a Windows installation of Python. In all three cases, the path printed was to the system's globally installed python libs. No warning was shown. I am making my virtual envs like this: `python3 -m venv venv`. Am I missing something in the virtual env creation?

Comment: The `virtualenv` method didn't quite work with my internal pypi host (haven't dug deeper why), but when I let it use the public pypi on my local workstation, the virtual env created did include the distutils shim! Actually it seems like it contains many more files and symlinks than the `-m venv` method includes. They seem quite a bit different! I'm assuming this is by design, but I don't know if the difference in distutils behaviour was intentional or a side-effect?

Comment: [It's part of `virtualenv`s logic](https://github.com/pypa/virtualenv/blob/master/virtualenv.py#L1500), you can't get around it.